# Problems with photo stream

Tags: macos, iphone, photos, photo-stream

I have a large photo library and I do not want to buy extra space from Apple so that I can use the iCloud photo library. Instead, I want to use the photo stream to synchronize every photo taken from my iPad and iPhone to my Mac (because here I have the space). And occasionally, I want to send some photos to my iPad/iPhone from my Mac.

So my problems with the photo stream are:

1. What happens when a photo is added to the photo stream? In the OS X photos App, it will be downloaded and permanently saved in the library, even if it is deleted from the photo stream. In iOS however, it will be downloaded but when removed from the photo stream it will disappear from my iOS device as well. Can I somehow save it there permanently like under OS X?
2. Some photos are not downloaded to my Mac although they are listed under the photo stream album on my iPhone, with which I took them. They are not listed in the photo stream album under the Photos App in OS X. What could be the problem?

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer your inquiries based on my experience.

1. In iOS, to be able to save an image from the Photo Stream (PS), you need to tap an image and select the Save Image action to make a copy of that image to the Camera Roll.
2. That may be a bug in iOS/OS X, I'm not sure, but that also happens to me especially with the most recent photos I took. But sometimes, after a couple of minutes, the Photos app on my Macbook Air will be updated. You can connect your iPhone to your Mac and just import those images that you can't see in your Photos app.